# How to update a session var while remaining on the same page in PHP?

Tags: php, session

On my page, users have the option to select a client. When they select one, this selection will be set in `$_SESSION['selectedClient']`. A user may then choose to pick a different client which would have to overwrite the current `$_SESSION['selectedClient']`. So when I try to update `$_SESSION['selectedClient']` it will show me that the session variable has updated. But when I reload the page it will show the previous/first selected client.

Here is the piece of code I currently have to try this:

```
if($_POST['clientEmail']){
   $_SESSION['selectedClient'] = $_POST['clientEmail'];
   echo '<script>document.location=\'\?p=home\';</script>';
}
```

The echo leads to the same PHP file in which I set session var and try to update the session var, which is needed in this case.

I've tried to unset `$_SESSION['selectedClient']` before assigning a new post like:

```
if($_POST['clientEmail']){
    unset($_SESSION['selectedClient']);
    $_SESSION['selectedClient'] = $_POST['clientEmail'];
    echo '<script>document.location=\'\?p=home\';</script>';
}
```

I haven't been able to find anything on google that could help me, which is why I decided to make a SO account and ask here. Feel free to ask if more information is needed.

EDIT:
When `$_SESSION['selectedClient']` is set and I select a new client, the post contains the newly selected value/client. After refresh, post is empty and session is reverted back to the client which was selected before.

selecting new client:

`_POST['clientEmail'] = >lol@lol.com<`
`_SESSION['selectedClient'] = >lol@lol.com<`

after refresh:

`_POST['clientEmail'] = ><`
`_SESSION['selectedClient'] = >login@login.com<`

Comment: I doubt `$_SESSION['selectedClient']` is the issue here. Most likely, `$_POST['clientEmail']` is changing the session to previous value. Please provide the value of it before and after page reload.

Comment: @Funk I've seen that question before but it didnt help me or I don't see the actual solution you're pointing at

Answer (score 1):

please make sure to use session_start in the beginning of file and use isset function to check if there is any POST data

```
session_start()
if(isset($_POST['clientEmail'])){
   $_SESSION['selectedClient'] = $_POST['clientEmail'];
   header("Location: .\?p=home");
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The pages are all handled through index.php. Basically in index.php I require a file which calls a method that has session_start(). With that said, all other session related stuff works fine as it is now. I will try this with `exit(0);`